# can any one explain this one with small examples

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between nodelist and array in javascript? Can we convert array to nodelist?

Comment: Check this for conversion...http://davidwalsh.name/nodelist-array

Answer (score 0):

I can give you the reference at most:

[nodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)

> NodeList objects are collections of nodes returned by Node.childNodes
>   and the querySelectorAll method.

[Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

> The JavaScript Array global object is a constructor for arrays, which
>   are high-level, list-like objects.

And here is David Walsh's blog : [Convert NodeList to Array](http://davidwalsh.name/nodelist-array) which suggest:

```
var nodesArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("div"));
```

Comment: The question is about difference between them, not about "what is it"

Comment: once user know what both is,  then it  will be easy to identify the differences

Comment: In particular, from [MDN NodeList page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList): `NodeList.prototype contains the item method, but none of the Array.prototype methods, so they cannot be used on NodeLists.`

Comment: I came here to look for `Array`->`NodeList`.